# cant parse reqbody json object when request variable is dynamic

Tags: json, unit-testing, postman-collection-runner, dynamic-variables, postman-testcase

i am working on test unit in postman ( test script )

the request body is :

```
{
"sessionKey": {{varsessionKey}},
"project_id": {{varproject_id}}
}
```

so i gave them data from json file

and in test script :

```
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw));
```

gave me error

> valid data type | JSONError: No value found for key sessionKey at 2:16 "sessionKey": somesessionKey, ^
>   POST

although the result of :

```
console.log(pm.request.body.raw);
```

> "{ "sessionKey": somesessionKey, "project_id": 1}"

and also if the request have static value not like {{var}} the json parse will work correctly

so my problem is that i cant access the variable inside the object like :

```
var req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
console.log(req.project_id);
```

any help is highly appreciated